# How to add the negative lookahead into an existing pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I know some basic concepts of regex. But when I need to but them together I'm failing. Here it IMHO comes to a negative lookahead. But I'm even not sure about if this is the right approach.

The input string is `#+foo: bar: lore`.

The regex (Python3) is `^#\+(.*): *(.*)$` and extract me this two groups.

```
#+foo: bar: lore
  ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^
```

The output *I wish* is

```
#+foo: bar: lore
  ^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Spoken in human language I would describe the first capturing group with "Everything after `#+` until the first `:`. The *problem* is that the *last* is used instead of the *first* `:`.

So I thought a negative lookahead would be the solution. I tried several things but none of them worked. Here is one approach.

```
^#\+(.*(?!:)): *(.*)$
       ^^^^^
```

Comment: You don't need lookahed. Use lazy quantifier: `^#\+(.*?): *(.*)$`

Comment: Try `^#\+(.*?): *(.*)$` where `?` causes as few characters as possible to be matched. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aUexZn/1). Alternatively, `^#\+([^:]*): *(.*)$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V40Gip/1).

Comment: The non-greedy quantifier is the best bet. The assertion equivalent is this `((?:(?!:).)*)` which checks that the next character is not a colon, preventing matching past it. This is usually slower but is 100% assured not to go past it, where as `.*?` is dependent upon the next expression in the regex. Cautionary tale ..!

Comment: I expect this to be marked as a duplicate, regardless of the hidden dangers of `.*?` that won't be mentioned or considered.

Comment: `^#\+([^:]*): *(.*)$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tBsCVs/1)